# Apache Pig: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm running `Pig 15` and am trying to group data here.  I'm running into a `Requested array size exceeds VM limit` error.  The file size is pretty small and takes just `10` mappers of `2.5G` each to run with no memory errors.

Below shown is a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
sample_set = LOAD 's3n://<bucket>/<dev_dir>/000*-part.gz' USING PigStorage(',') AS (col1:chararray,col2:chararray..col23:chararray);
sample_set_group_by_col1 = GROUP sample_set BY col1;
sample_set_group_by_col1_10 = LIMIT sample_set_group_by_col1 10;
DUMP sample_set_group_by_col1_10;
```

This job fails with the following error:

```
2016-08-08 14:28:59,622 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
at org.apache.pig.data.utils.SedesHelper.writeChararray(SedesHelper.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeDatum(BinInterSedes.java:580)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeDatum(BinInterSedes.java:462)
at org.apache.pig.data.utils.SedesHelper.writeGenericTuple(SedesHelper.java:135)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeTuple(BinInterSedes.java:650)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeBag(BinInterSedes.java:641)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeDatum(BinInterSedes.java:474)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeDatum(BinInterSedes.java:462)
at org.apache.pig.data.utils.SedesHelper.writeGenericTuple(SedesHelper.java:135)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeTuple(BinInterSedes.java:650)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinInterSedes.writeDatum(BinInterSedes.java:470)
at org.apache.pig.data.BinSedesTuple.write(BinSedesTuple.java:40)
at org.apache.pig.impl.io.PigNullableWritable.write(PigNullableWritable.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:98)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:198)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.spillSingleRecord(MapTask.java:1696)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1180)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:712)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Map.collect(PigGenericMapReduce.java:135)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:281)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:274)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
```

Has anybody come across this error before? If yes, what's the solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'pretty small file', does it have much less than 2^31 rows? Are you on 64 bit? And what do you mean by 'run with no memory errors'? -- What is the memory that your containers request and what is the actual available memory for them?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Small files (10 files of size ~300M and ~6M records). Yes, it's a 64 bit. Memory errors in the sense did not run into Mapper/Reducer OOM. Containers request 2.5G and available memory is 21G.  Does this help?

Comment: It helps eliminate and clarify things, but unfortunately does not yet point at a solution. Have you tried running the code for a smaller set (putting a limit directly after the load?) I notice that you don't have a typical 'forach, generate, flatten' command after the group, so perhaps the output is much larger than you might expect. Also, to be safe consider using store rather than dump to eliminate the impact of 'debugging'.

Answer (score 0):

From error it looks like the output of GROUP BY statement is huge. This huge record created doesn't fit into Java Heap Space currently available. Normally Hadoop Mappers and Reducer tasks are allocated 1GB of heap space. Try increasing java heap size while running this pig script by following parameter.

```
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb 4096;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 6144;
```

If it still doesn't work, try increasing the size more using above parameters.